# Heap out of memory when building

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving the error below when trying to build and deploy our react application.

> FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Whereas I think that this is purely a JavaScript issue, I'm not sure whether I can rule out anything related to our cloud setup: A bit bucket pipeline which pushes the bundle to an S3 bucket (AWS) and is exposed via a Cloudfront distribution (AWS).

I've searched for a solution, and saw that this could be solved by increasing the max_old_space_size. I changed the react scripts as follows (added --max_old_space_size=6000), but this did not do the trick.

```
"scripts": {
   ...
  "build:dev": "REACT_APP_ENV=development npm run build --max_old_space_size=6000",
}
```

Any help would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by upgrading the RAM from 1 to 2 GB (t2.micro - t2.small).

We came to this conclusion by running series of test in VM(Virtual Machine) by replicating the same environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the response. I assume that you're working with EC2 instances then? In our setup, we have a JS (React) frontend connecting with a Django backend. The frontend bundle is pushed to an S3 bucket and exposed via a cloudfront distribution, whereas the backend is done via a EB setup/ EC2 instances.
Where exactly should this RAM upgrade be made? I do not have the possibility to se this for the cloudfront distribution I think

Comment: Have you considered diving into the code, may be there is a js code doing heavy computation that needs to be optimized ? or may be there is a memory leak ?

Comment: Hi Arsany, thanks for your answer. Any idea on how I could check the memory leak? Only small updates where done compared to the previous (succesfull) deployment, so no idea where it could've gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try this script

```
    "scripts": {
  "build:dev": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=6000 REACT_APP_ENV=development npm run build",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was caused by enabling source maps for sentry so I can get more readable stack traces...

Everything's fine after I disabled it.

EDIT: I actually removed everything sentry-related from my vite.config.js